# Making a database helper class for a table with many fields

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm currently trying to learn how to use a SQLite database with android. I've managed to successfully follow http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/ but I'm now looking to make a table with 25-30 fields. It seems like it would be a huge task to type out all this in a similar style to that link especially as I'd want to be able to search by many of those fields.

Is there something I can use to automatically generate a database helper class with this number of fields and methods to search them? Or am I going about this completely the wrong way?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but at first I don't see anything unreasonable in that code, except for the lack of transactions (but I understand that it may be just an initial example --- KISS). The object model seems OK at first, and keep in mind that it won't be a huge task to add more fields... you keep the structure and add only the relevant fields and parameters. besides, you do have many fields, so you'll add all that much anyway...

Comment: But in that example for creating the table it took 3 lines to make the string for 3 fields. Does this mean that the only way for me to make this table is to type out around 30 lines? And then on top of that have huge methods for searching?

Comment: I'm not an expert in SQL (hence me commenting, not answering), but won't you have to define the SQL structure anyway? You could abstract the logical SQL structure into helper methods, but you're going to define it somewhere. You're going to define at least the column names, but the structure can be abstracted. The sql command to create the columns can then be fed into a loop. I don't know what you mean by "huge methods for searching". it's my understanding that you only need to select the columns you actually care about when searching. If all, most Android classes I've seen use a null.

Answer (score 0):

First off i just recently started android programming also and i particularly enjoyed this tutorial about databases : http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

To generate the queries i think it will be better you use an SQLite Database Manager and just copy and past your queries in the methods.

Comment: Thanks for the link - Looks like a helpful read. Also thanks for the idea of copy & paste with the queries.